# How to parse a text file into a protobuf MessageLite object in C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Generally, I can call the `google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parse` to parse a prototxt file into a `Message`. But now I have to use `MessageLite` for some reason. Since TextFormat takes only Message*, the conversion fails. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing you got downvoted because the documentation for `TextFormat::Parse` says to use `MessageLite::ParseFromString` when you don't have a `Message` but a `MessageLite`.  Still, it would be polite to mark the @P.W answer as _the_ answer.

Comment: @JesseChisholm MessageLite::ParseFromString() uses different non-human readable format, albeit in string type.

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageLite` class has a `ParseFromString` member with the following signature.

```
bool MessageLite::ParseFromString(const string & data)
```

This parses a protocol buffer contained in a string.
For more details, you can refer
to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite.ParseFromString.details) on this.

Comment: As per your linked documentation _"This function takes a string in the **(non-human-readable) binary** wire format"_, which is not what TextFormat supports.

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf Lite does not support reflection, which is needed for implementing [human-readable text format](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/textformat-spec/#working-with-the-format-programmatically) parser. Therefore it's not possible to read a message in this format using the Lite version.